# optimize calculating Document Frequency

Tags: python, nlp

This takes too long:

```
# Document-frequency
phrases_final["doc_freq"] = len(phrases_final) * [0]


# for each phrase, compute the number of clusters that phrase occurs in

for phrase in phrases_final["extracted_phrases"]:
    for i in cluster_name:
        all_tweets = ""
        for tweet in df["tweets_to_consider"][df.cl_num == i]:
            all_tweets = all_tweets + tweet + ". "
        if phrase in all_tweets:
            phrases_final["doc_freq"][
                (phrases_final.extracted_phrases == phrase) & (phrases_final.cluster_num == i)
            ] = (
                phrases_final["doc_freq"][
                    (phrases_final.extracted_phrases == phrase) & (phrases_final.cluster_num == i)
                ]
                + 1
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should probably precalculate `all_tweets` for each cluster, not do it again for each phrase.

  - Alternately, you might not want to construct `all_tweets` at all, since `if phrase in (long_string_here)` will be slow; consider a dict of sets, maybe?
- Instead of computing results directly into a dataframe (at least I assume it's a dataframe from the indexing, though honestly you're initializing `phrases_final` as a list of integers, so the indexing may be entirely bogus anyway), consider a `collections.Counter()` indexed by a `(cluster_num, phrase)` tuple (or a `collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)` indexed by `cluster_num`, then `phrase`).
- If things are still too slow, use a `multiprocessing.Pool()` to parallelize this over either the phrases or the clusters.